# How to use pivot clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

How can I transform the table from the left in the table from the right? I used the pivot clause but is not working. This is what I tried:

```
select *
from   (
  select categ, name from students
)
pivot (count(books) for name in('Tom', 'Jane'));
```

[image]

Comment: when you pivot, you count BOOKS.  There is no such column selected in your subquery. Do you have a column BOOKS in the STUDENTS table? If you do, you must select it also, before you pivot.

Comment: Yes, I have a books column in the students table.I added to line 2: select categ, name, books from students, but is still not working. I get this error: error near line 2: near "(" : syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE students ( categ, name, books ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'Jane', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Tom',  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Jane', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Jane', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Tom',  1 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
select Categ, jane, tom
from   ( select categ, name, books from students )
pivot ( MAX(books) for name in ('Tom' AS tom, 'Jane' AS jane));
```

**Output**:

```
     CATEG       JANE        TOM
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3
         2          4           
         3          0          1
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! : )

Answer (score -1):

One example I created yesterday was:

Suppose you got a table like:

Name    Salary 
Mark      3000 
David     4000 
Kyal      15000 
Jhon      10000

Then below query can generate result shown below:

```
SELECT [Mark], [David], [Kyal], [Jhon] 
FROM 
( SELECT Name, Salary 
FROM EmpSalary ) AS MainTable 
PIVOT 
( 
SUM(Salary) 
FOR Name IN ([Mark], [David], [Kyal], [Jhon]) 
) AS PT; 

Output: 

Mark   David   Kyal   Jhon 
3000   4000   15000   10000
```

Hope that's what you wanted to achieve.

Manoj.

Comment: The `[]` syntax is not valid in Oracle. This appears to be an answer for SQL Server.